# Webdriver Assertions fail after swicthing to Java 8

Tags: java, selenium

After switching to Java 8 , many of the webdriver assertions fail when it tries to assert something before the element is rendered. It just seems like the speed of rendering and the Java tests isnt in sync. The Webdriver being used in the project is Selenium-chrome-driver-2.43.1. I haven't tried this for other browsers. Is there anyhow I could make this work without putting too many 'wait for elements'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implicit or explicit waits.

Implicit influence all requests, easier if application is generally slow, so you want to bump up the wait for all requests. But setting it too high may cause test to be waiting for long time in cases when you don't want to:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Explicit waits give you more flexibility, but require more work. For example say you want most of your operations to complete within 10 sec, so you set implicit wait above to 10 sec. But say you know that the following operation may fail with implicit wait, because this particular element takes 15 sec on average to show up:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

So you can change it to:

```
 WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20))
         .until(newExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: By increasing the implicit wait time to 10 seconds from 5 seconds, the time of running all tests has doubled but failures are still the same. I have also tried adding wait after each action, e.g. click, submit. That works for now, though not a neat solution. I have also tried upgrading to latest selenium webdriver - 27.1, and updated chrome, doesn't help passing the tests though.

Comment: @Avatar: by "also tried adding wait after each action" do you mean the selenium wait (e.g. WebDriverWait or FluentWait)?
If yes, I think it's the right solution, unfortunately. Many years with selenium have taught me that if you want tests to be reliable, you have to search for elements using such waits, especially if you have dynamic webapps.
As for elegance, of course in practice I would not recommend to put that WebDriverWait piece of code every time you do a search or focus. Usually you can isolate about 5-10 wait patterns you need for your application, so wrap them in reusable functions.